# Apps suddenly quitting or freezing? Memory problem?

Tags: ms-office, google-chrome, memory

I have a MacBook Pro (2018, 13-inch) with Catalina.

Every once in a while, my mac gets weird. All the tabs open on Chrome go black and if I try to reload, the whole app usually just quits. Other apps freeze as well. 
My open Word documents also suddenly get different file names (like .W89712 or something) and get saved to a strange different folder (com.microsoft.Word).

Is this just a memory problem? I feel like I don't run anything crazy on my computer. Mostly just Chrome, Word (1-2 documents), Acrobat (1-2 documents) and the Mail app.

Comment: Hi @Jonas!  You can check system resources hogging in Activity Monitor.

Comment: Chrome is a known resource hog, I’d try a different browser.  Also, if you want to test out hardware, boot into [Apple Diagnostic mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) by holding D when powering up.  You can also try [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) by holding Shift while booting.  This should help you isolate issues